# stdio.h contains definition or declaration of functions?

Tags: c, stdio

I read that the stdio.h header file contains function declarations (with prototypes), macro definitions and definitions of data types. But when I opened the file in VSCode it contained function definitions too — not sure if they are definitions or something else. Please explain the following. What is this code doing? More importantly, is it function definition?

**mingw_stdio_redirect**

```
int fprintf (FILE *__stream, const char *__format, ...)
{ 
    register int __retval;

    __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );

    __retval = __mingw_vfprintf( __stream, __format, __local_argv );

    __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );

    return __retval; 
}
```

**mingw_stdio_redirect**

```
int printf (const char *__format, ...)
{
    register int __retval;

    __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );

    __retval = __mingw_vprintf( __format, __local_argv );

    __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );

    return __retval;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have quoted appears to be definitions of functions.

Header files *that you create* should contain only

- *definitions* of macros
- *definitions* of structures, unions, and typedef-names
- *declarations* of variables
- *declarations* of functions, in the form of prototypes

Later (once your C skills have advanced somewhat) you might also include

- *definitions* of `inline` functions

A compiler implementer, on the other hand, may put anything they like in their header files, as long as their compiler behaves the way the language standard says it must. You should rely only on the compiler's documentation, and not on anything you might intuit from reading other files supplied with the compiler, to understand its behaviour.

A compiler implementer is permitted to use any magic they choose, including having the compiler *Just Know* what the system headers are required by the Standard to define and declare without any actual files for those headers, and if they so choose they may even provide "header" files containing bogus or misleading contents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it completely compiler-specific? Moreover, even though it is an inline implementation of that function, it calls __mingw_vprintf. Even if you see the definition of vprintf (at least in my header file), it calls itself. Isn't the source code of vprintf present in the compiled form in C runtime library? If that's the case, then isn't it just transferring the call to vprintf which depends on the library code?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should add the complete function definition as supposed to be from `MinGW` which appears to be:

```
__mingw_ovr
__attribute__((__format__ (gnu_printf, 1, 2))) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NONNULL(1)
int printf (const char *__format, ...)
{
  register int __retval;
  __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );
  __retval = __mingw_vprintf( __format, __local_argv );
  __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );
  return __retval;
}
```

which is is found quite different from the original `GNU` `stdio.h` found here :
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/stdio.h.html

Either way mingw looks like it has function definitions in header file. And if you look at 
`#define __mingw_ovr static __attribute__ ((__unused__)) __inline__ __cdecl` 
what `__mingw_ovr` is it - it appears that is an `inline` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it completely compiler-specific? Moreover, even though it is an inline implementation of that function, it calls __mingw_vprintf. Even if you see the definition of vprintf, it calls itself. Isn't the source code (present in a compiled form) of vprintf present in the C runtime library?

Comment: It's compiler specific. `__mingw_vprinf` is an `extern` function, which by default are functions in C. It's implementation is elsewhere. If you want to find all answers, just explore MinGW source code and see for yourself.

Comment: Hey, you said that MinGW has function definitions in its header file. If that is true then why is the below code running perfectly fine just by providing prototypes?
                                                                            int printf(char *, ...);

int main(void) 
{
    printf("Hello World");
}                                                                                     Aren't the definitions present in the C runtime library then?

Answer (score -1):

According to C-language standard draft

> 7.21 Input/output
>
> 7.21.1
>
> Introduction
>
> 1 The header  defines several macros, and
>   declares three types and many functions for performing input and
>   output.
>
> 2 The types declared are size_t (described in 7.19);

Link -> http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf  (page - 314)

As for what the code is doing: It prints formatted data to the stream.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about the function definitions.